# 'n' number of CAML queries in a single executeQueryAsync function

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, caml-query, jsom, caml

How to execute 'n' number of CAML queries to get a different list of objects? We can use multiple `clientContext.load()` if we have a defined number of queries like `clientContext.load(collListItem); clientContext.load(collListItem1);`

In my scenario, the queries are generated and cannot determine the number of CAML queries needs to be executed. Is this possible?

```
clientContext.load(collListItem1);
clientContext.load(collListItem2);
...
...
clientContext.load(collListItemN);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used window keyword to create dynamic variables to achieve the above scenario.

```
var oList = clientContext
    .get_web()
    .get_lists()
    .getByTitle("List Name");
  for (index = 0, i = 1; some_valid _condition; index++, i++) {
    window["camlQuery" + i] = new SP.CamlQuery();
    window["camlQuery" + i].set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ParentId1' /><Value Type='Text'>" + parentID[index] + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"); //A sample CAML Query
    this.window["collListItem" + i] = oList.getItems(window["camlQuery" + i]);
    clientContext.load(window["collListItem" + i]);
  }
```

This is tested and working fine for me.